# Windows 11, Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, combine

[image]

Is there perhaps a formaula that can combine the informations in multiple cells into one in another cell - I know I am not asking this correctly.
Please see below picture:

I need te information either broken down into different cells, or combined from the different cells into one.

Answer (score 1):

Using `TEXTSPLIT()` or `FILTERXML()` or a combination of `MID()`, `TRIM()` , `REPT()` & `SUBSTITUTE()` functions can be split/broken into different cells.

Using `TEXTSPLIT()` --> Applicable to `MS365` exclusively.

[image]

---

```
=TEXTSPLIT(A1,"-")
```

---

Using `FILTERXML()` --> Applicable from `Excel 2013+` onwards (only Excel for desktop and Windows).

[image]

---

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","</b><b>")&"'</b></m>","//b"))
```

---

Or, The following needs to fill across.

```
=FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE($A1,"-","</b><b>")&"'</b></m>","//b["&COLUMN(A1)&"]")
```

---

Or, Using some combined functions. --> Applicable to `Excel 2010+` onwards and needs to fill across.

[image]

---

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"-",REPT(" ",100)),COLUMN(A1)*100-99,100))
```

---

And if needs to combine from different cells then using `TEXTJOIN()`

[image]

---

```
=TEXTJOIN("-",,B1:F1)
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

```
=SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT("-"&B1:F1),"-",,1)
```

---